# Migrating from requirejs to webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, requirejs

I'm migrating/moving a project based on require.js to webpack v3. Since all my modules are using the following syntax:

```
    define([modules,..], function(mod1,..)
```

Which declares which modules to use, and assigns the modules to the variables in the anonymous function. This seems to be deprecated since v2 of webpack. I can't find any information about this (except for the documentation for web pack v1).

Should I rewrite all my modules to the commonjs (including dependencies) or are there any smart way to use the AMD modules?

Help much appreciated :-)
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMD never found much use outside of requirejs so likely you will need to convert.  There are tools that will help:

- https://github.com/anodynos/uRequire can convert code from AMD -> UMD / CommonJS

There are caveats from (https://github.com/anodynos/uRequire/wiki/nodejs-Template):

- Runtime translation of paths like models/PersonModel to ../../models/PersonModel, depending on where it was called from. You 'll still get build-time translated bundleRelative paths, to their nodejs fileRelative equivalent.

For most projects this is not an issue.

- Can't use the asynchronous version of require(['dep'], function(dep){...})

You should be able to use the synchronous version of require.  If using webpack2 you can use `System.import` or `require.ensure`

- Can't run requirejs loader plugins, like text!... or json!...

You will find webpack version of all of these plugins

- There's no mapping of /, ie webRootMap etc or using the requirejs.config's {baseUrl:"...."} or {paths:"lib":"../../lib"}

This can be replicated with https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-alias

Comment: Thanks for your reply @CaptEmulation. I found out that webpack support amd out of the box, but my problem seems to be elsewhere. Using pager.js with knockout doesn't initialize correctly (claims that pager is undefined eventhough I have required it)

Comment: Feel free to put on a public repo and provide link if you want another set of eyes

Comment: I've create a public repo with only the essential files: [link](https://github.com/svendlove/front) @CaptEmulation thanks for your time!

Comment: you run it with "npm install" and afterwards "npm run start" :) @CaptEmulation

Comment: Thank you very much - worked like a charm :-) Also I found out that a lot of the libraries I'm using has to be called manually, properly because of the way they are imported. I'm new to stackoverflow - can I give you points somehow?

Comment: forgot to tag :)

Answer (score 0):

The *CaptEmulation*'s answer is not valid for newer Webpack versions. Webpack supports AMD natively (neither additional loaders, nor plugins need to be installed). A thorough instruction is available here: https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods.

This fact may easily go unnoticed when one tries to rewrite a RequireJS-based build to Webpack, as RequireJS uses relative paths without the trailing `./`, e.g.

```
define('app/dep1', function(dep1) { ... });
```

which will not pass in Webpack without additional configuration (assuming that both `require.config.js` and `webpack.config.js` are in the same directory):

```
{
   resolve: {
      modules: [ './', ... ] // other entries possible here
   }
}
```